# Why can't my program process when I input a number above 99999

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple program where it calculates how much time I have left considering my only expense is 500 each month and I can only put an initial amount one time. But when I start inputting a number larger than 99999 for the initial value, the program keeps buffering and do not load anymore. I have tried changing data types such as long but it still loads forever. Any logic or idea behind this, I am new to this so please educate me.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double WITHDRAW = 500.00; 
        final double INTEREST_RATE_PER_MONTH =  0.06/12.0;
        int months = 0;
        int years; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you are going to deposit to your Initial Balance:");
        double bal = in.nextDouble();

        do {
            bal += (INTEREST_RATE_PER_MONTH * bal) - WITHDRAW;
            months ++; 
        }
        while (bal > 0);

        years = months / 12; 
        
        if (years == 0) {

            String msg = "";
            msg = months + " month";

            if (months > 1){
                msg = msg + "s";
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(msg);
        }
        else if (years == 1){
            months = months - 12;
            String msg = "";
            msg =  years + " year and " +  months + " month";

            if (months > 1){
                msg = msg + "s";
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(msg);
            
        }
        else if (years > 1){
            months = months % years; 
            String msg = "";
            msg = years + " years and " + months + " month";

            if (months > 1){
                msg = msg + "s";
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(msg);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("0 month");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you have an infinite loop

```
do {
            bal += (INTEREST_RATE_PER_MONTH * bal) - WITHDRAW;
            months ++; 
        }
        while (bal > 0);
```

this loop could only end if your balance reaches 0

which it wont if the interest per month is larger than your withdraw.

this happens when your balance is larger than 100000  (500/(0.06/12.0))

Answer (score 0):

actually when you input a number above 100000,the monthly interest has exceeded the monthly withdraw amount,so your money will grow more and more until the bar overflow.
but the max value of the bar = MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308 is too huge

the algorithm to calculate the bar

```
bal += (INTEREST_RATE_PER_MONTH * bal) - WITHDRAW;
```

grows too slowly(It takes about 2000 loops to increase tenfold),but init value you input(eg:1 billion) is 10^300 times worse than the Double.MAX_VALUE,that means the cpu needs to compute about 10^300 to overflow.the time of compute will contines to the end of the world

After the bal value is set to overflow, bal=infinite>0, any addition or subtraction operation on bal at this time is bal, so it will never exit the loop